# lighttpd web server - 403 forbidden

Tags: raspberry-pi, privileges, lighttpd

I am trying to load a HTML file called `index.html` on to my Lighttpd web server that will display just some simple text and an image.

The issue is that each time I put the Raspberry Pi's IP address into the address bar I keep getting the `403 - Forbidden` error message.

`ls -al` on my index.html file gives:

`-rwxr-xrwx 1 root root 351 Dec 20 16:52 /var/www/html/index.html` where the file path is highlighted in green.

I have tried numerous combinations of ownership between `www-data, root` and `pi` but I cant seem to solve the issue.  The other thing I have tried is changing the document root in the `Lighttpd.conf` file to `/var/www/` so the file can be accessed.

Can anyone offer some assistance please? Many thanks

Comment: "chmod 777 -R /var/www/html" might solve this issue. This will recursively set the directory and all its files to read write all permissions (! Security Vulnerability)

Answer (score 2):

if you write index.html in /var/www/html folder without having permission issue you should change the permission or ownership

```
sudo chmod www-data:www-data -r html



Check /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf
if 
server.username = "www-data"
and server.groupname too
```

also make sure

```
server.document-root = "/var/www/html"
```

And restart the server

```
systemctl restart lighttpd
```